# MATLAB regular expression; how to find 1 or 2 repeated characters

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to find strings that start with one or more dashes ('-', or '--').

```
>> Strs = {'nope', '-yes', '--yesAgain', 'not-this-one', '---notThisOneEither'};
>> regexp(Strs, '^-{1,2}')
ans =
    []    [1]    [1]    []    [1]
```

Why does my regular expression return 1 for the final test string? According to the regexp documentation expr{m,n} "matches the expression when it occurs at leats m times, but no more than n times consecutively", so "-{1,2}" should find instances of `"-"` and `"--"` but should ignore instances of `"---"`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex finds *partial* matches. In order to avoid that, you need to explicitly tell the regex engine to fail the match if there are more hyphens after 1 or 2 hyphens.

So, you may use a *negative lookahead* at the end of the patten:

```
^-{1,2}(?!-)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qwZMwd/1)

Since the `(?!-)` lookahead is a *zero-width assertion*, it will allow matching `-` and `--` strings.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can change regexp as follows:

```
regexp(Strs, '^-{1,2}[^-]')
```

To say, after one or two minuses, no more minuses.

Comment: FYI, the `'^-{1,2}[^-]'` regex won't match `--` nor `-` strings.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, you are right. Thank you. Your solution better.

Comment: I remain it, as it may be helpful for parsing options, where no assumed '-' or '--' flags.

Comment: I also was about to add that you actually can fix it easily by adding an alternation group at the end of the pattern.